# dialogflow BasicCard, how to get it working on android application?

Tags: javascript, android, dialogflow-es

I have tried almost everything out but I might be missing little trivial thing, don't know what exactly so here I go.

We have made an app for android currently and trying to integrate Dialogflow in it. We would love to have BasicCard or something similar implemented in the app.

Using dialogflow gui, i have hard coded response in it which works currently as shown [image: below].

But when I try to do it using this code in dialogflow inline editor,

```js
'use strict';
const {
  dialogflow,
  SimpleResponse,
  BasicCard,
  Button,
  Image,
  BrowseCarousel,
  BrowseCarouselItem,
  Suggestions,
  LinkOutSuggestion,
  MediaObject,
  Table,
  List,
  Carousel,
} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');


const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('TestRichResponse', (conv) => {
  if (!conv.screen) {
    conv.ask('Sorry, try this on a screen device or select the ' +
      'phone surface in the simulator.');
    conv.ask('Which response would you like to see next?');
    return;
  }

  conv.ask(`Here's an example of a basic card.`);
  conv.ask(new BasicCard({
    text: `hi`,
    subtitle: 'hi',
    title: 'hi',
    buttons: new Button({
      title: 'hi',
      url: 'https://assistant.google.com/',
    }),
    image: new Image({
      url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
      alt: 'hi',
    }),
    display: 'CROPPED',
  }));
  conv.ask('Which response would you like to see next?');
});


exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I get following "Cannot display response in Dialogflow simulator. Please test on the Google Assistant simulator instead.".
Yes, It works fine on google assistant simulator but i want to recreate exactly same thing as i did before using Javascript in inline editor because i have to show different card for different questions and i dont want to end up in tons of intents.

And also because when I make card with using Dialogflow as shown in first pic, it works in my app, but when I do it using the code above, it says the same msg "Cannot display..."

Any help would be really really appreciated to recreate the thing in first pic using Javascript code pls. (App is made using flutter)